# plone.app.jquerytools Bad version error while installing PloneFormGen

Tags: plone, jquery-tools, buildout, egg, ploneformgen

I am trying to install zettwerk.ui theme , i have added zettwerk.ui to eggs = then ran

buildout and restarted plone but i didn't find the theme on the Addon page.

here is buildout output

```
Uninstalling backup.
--
Uninstalling zopeskel.
--
Installing instance.
--
The version, 1.1.2, is not consistent with the requirement, 
--
'plone.app.jquerytools>=1.2dev'.
-
While:
-
  Installing instance.
--
Error: Bad version 1.1.2
--
*************** PICKED VERSIONS ****************
--
[versions]
--
Products.PloneFormGen = 1.7a2
--
beyondskins.ploneday.site2011 = 1.0
--
collective.recaptcha = 1.1.1
--
recaptcha-client = 1.0.6
--
zettwerk.ui = 0.33
--
Required by:
--
Products.PloneFormGen 1.7a2
--
collective.js.jqueryui = 1.8.12.2
--
*************** /PICKED VERSIONS ***************
--
```

Comment: Could someone rename that question into 'plone.app.jquerytools Bad version error while installing PloneFormGen' to make it re useable outside ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

zettwerk.ui has no dependencies to plone.app.jquerytools. This comes from Products.PloneFormGen. Pin it to 1.6.0 to make you buildout runs again by adding the following to your buildout.cfg:

```
[versions]
Products.PloneFormGen = 1.6.0
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use PloneFormGen 1.7 on Plone 4.0, it clearly notes the extra dependency on its PyPi page at http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Products.PloneFormGen/1.7a2 in the "1.7 Notes" paragraph.